# Calculate $\lim{a_{n}}$ for $a_{n}=((1+\frac{1}{n^{2}})^{n^{2}}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n}))^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$a_{n}=((1+\frac{1}{n^{2}})^{n^{2}}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n}))^{n}=(e^{\ln((1+\frac{1}{n^{2}})^{n^{2}})+\ln((1-\frac{1}{n})^{n})+\ln((1+\frac{1}{n})^{n})})^{n}$$
Then I can use Taylor's theorem - because function $f(x)=e^{x}$ is monotonic I can examine $\ln((1+\frac{1}{n^{2}})^{n^{2}})+\ln((1-\frac{1}{n})^{n})+\ln((1+\frac{1}{n})^{n})$. 
However I think it is too time-consuming and there is probably a faster way.
Have you some ideas?

Comment: The sleepy calculus student would say, why isn't the answer $e e^{-1} e$? And then say, not so fast,  maybe it's a trick question with a subtle reason for why the obvious answer is wrong.

Comment: The (superscript) powers in your logarithmic terms should be $n^3$, $n^2$, and $n$, not $n^2$, $n$, and $n$.

Comment: Expanding $\log (1+x)$ up to the term in $x^{2}$ seems to be the simplest way. But exclude the last factor from your calculations to make it simpler; we know that $(1+\frac 1n )^{n} \to e$ so you can keep this separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e$$ as $n \to \infty$. As for
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^3} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$$
take logarithms and use $\log(1 + x) = x - x^2/2 + \dots$ as $x \to 0$ to get 
$$ n^3 \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) + n^2 \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)= n - \dots - n - \frac{1}{2} - \dots \to -\frac{1}{2}$$ as $n \to \infty$. 
Thus the limit is $$e^{-1/2} e = \sqrt{e}.$$